# how to point a XPath to a following-sibling/text()?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML with a sequence of tags and text,

```
     <table-wrap id="t01"> <label>Tabela 1</label>aaaa <caption>...</caption>
         ...
     </table-wrap>
```

and need to delete the text "aaaa", that is a following-sibling of label tag.
I have a XSLT identity transform for this task, something like

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!-- identity -->
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table-wrap/label::following-sibling/text()" />
```

the problem is **how to express the XPath of the following-sibling text?**

PS: the xpath of the example is wrong, is only illustrative. I try `table-wrap/label/following-sibling::text()` and others, and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed you want to remove the text if they come anywhere after `<label>` element at the same level. (If you just want to remove them if they come immediately after a `<label>` element, that is a fairly trivial change.)

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Matches any text nodes that are children of the table-wrap element, as long as
       they have a label element as a preceding sibling. -->
  <xsl:template match="table-wrap/text()[preceding-sibling::label]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output when applied to your example input XML:

```
<table-wrap id="t01">
  <label>Tabela 1</label><caption>...</caption></table-wrap>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aaaa` string is actually the text of the `table-wrap` node since it is not wrapped in another element. That being the case you can update your template match to the below.

```
<xsl:template match="table-wrap/text()" />
```